# How to get model value from textbox which is binded from dropdown without changing the model value of dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my project I have a drop down and a text box in a Angular html page.
From drop down I select a option , after selecting that option it got binded to textbox. Later I need to change the value of textbox and submit it. I need to latest change value on button click to submit.
How to get the latest value on submit?

```
<select ng-model="val" ng-change="select(val);" ng-options="gro.name for gro in group"></select>

<input type="text" value="{{val.name}}" />
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-model instead of value

In HTML

```
<select ng-model="val" ng-change="select(val);" ng-options="gro.name for gro in group"></select>

<input type="text" ng-model="selectedValue" />
```

In controller on change, (i.e ng-change) this will be called and it will update.

```
function select(val) {
$scope.selectedValue = val;
}
```

Later if you change in text box, ng-model value (i.e selectedValue) will be binded to the latest value and won't change in dropdown, because dropdown ng-model is different (i.e val).